# When Arduino meets Android

Tags: android, communication, arduino

I read the [Android Open Accessory Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html) and I noticed that:

> The Android 3.1 platform (also backported to Android 2.3.4) introduces
>   Android Open Accessory support, which allows external USB hardware (an
>   Android USB accessory) to interact with an Android-powered device in a
>   special "accessory" mode.

So, the [Arduino Mega 2560 ADK](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK) is supposed to work with android device above 3.1? 'Cause I tried to make it work, but my device is currently 2.2.1, so i guess that's why it wasn't working...

Despite that... Why is the [IOIO board](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10748) working with the 1.5 device? Because the IOIO is also based on the Android Open ADK?

Does anyone have a clue...?

Or is there any way the Mega ADK is able to communicate with android 2.X...?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what arduino libraries do you use to connect the arduino to android. as far as I know... Arduino Mega 2560 ADK has an USB host interface and can communicate starting with android 2.2.3
you can check [Google's ADK documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html)